# Non-EU Spouse (USA) of an Irish Citizen, work rights in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, eu-spouses, usa

I am a US citizen, with resident status in Ireland as the spouse of an Irish Citizen. We will be moving in the next six weeks to London, and I am not clear on my rights to work in the UK as the spouse of an EU/Irish citizen.

It appears I do not need to get the EEA Family Permit, but should get a residence card on arrival. Am I allowed to work before receiving the residence card? Is completing the EEA Family Permit even though not legally necessary - a way to be able to work on arrival?

Any information appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Article 23 of Directive 2004/38/EC (the Free Movement Directive) allows the family members of EEA nationals who have the right of residence in the UK to work or become self-employed. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/779784/free-movement-rights-direct-family-members-of-EEA-nationals-v7.0ext.pdf

The Family Permit is primarily an entry clearance document (for you to enter the country), not a residence document. All employers are required to check the right to work of a prospective employee https://www.gov.uk/legal-right-work-uk Without a Residence Card you will need to provide the employer with alternative evidence of your right to work https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/720858/29_06_18_Employer_s_guide_to_right_to_work_checks.pdf#page38

Comment: In addition, the OP should note that in the event of a no-deal Brexit on 31st October, any rights from the Free Movement Directive will cease to exist.  The British Government has said that people who are *already* in the UK will have their rights protected (but that was principally in the context of EU citizens), but there won't be much to stop the British Government changing its policy.

Comment: Thank you so much Traveller! This was my general understanding, but after going through several UK gov pages, I wasn't clear.

Comment: @MeriahNunn you should be able to prove your right to work with a certificate of application, but actually you are authorized by law to work as soon as you get to the UK.  The problem is that employers probably will not recognize that right unless you have the C of A or a residence card.

Comment: @phoog Thank you for this follow up! I am applying for jobs at the moment, and keep hitting the question of if I have a visa to work. My sense is that I can answer yes to this? Am I correct in understanding I do not need to do anything prior to arrival, but then apply for the residence card once we are in London? Thanks again!

Comment: @MeriahNunn I think I would answer "yes" if the context requires a yes or no answer.  Technically, EU/EEA/Swiss citizens and their family members don't have a "visa" to work. If the context allows a free-form answer, I'd probably say "I'm authorized to work as the spouse of an Irish citizen." If they ask whether you actually have the residence card or certificate of application in hand, of course, you'll have to say no, and you may want to avoid saying that in the initial stages of contact with a potential employer.

Comment: @MartinBonner but OP's spouse is Irish, so will certainly retain the right to move to and work in the UK.  I do not know what the rights of non-EU spouses of Irish citizens will be after the end of free movement; it's an interesting question that I haven't considered before now.

Comment: It would not surprise me to discover that the officials in the immigration department of the Home Office haven't considered it yet either ...

Comment: @MartinBonner while I was looking just now for the pending changes, which I did not find, it occurred to me that the answer is probably fairly straightforward: the qualifying family of an Irish citizen who is in the UK in time to participate in the settled status scheme will be able to use that scheme (the same is true of the family of any EU/EEA/Swiss citizen), while the family of an Irish citizen who is not participating in that scheme will have to use the very expensive route laid out in appendix FM of the immigration rules (as do family of British citizens and other "settled" people).

Comment: @phoog Thank you for all your help! What you've noted here has been what I've been able to find myself. As far as I can tell since we will be arriving pre-Brexit changes (mid Sept), and my spouse EU will be availing of the settled status scheme, then I will be able to as well. The question itself was in regards to having a visa, and was a yes or no. I simply answered yes as I will have the right to work without requiring sponsorship. I appreciate all the clarifications!

Comment: @MeriahNunn it occurs to me to note that actually employers are not "required to check the right to work of a prospective employee" but rather having checked in accordance with the law serves as a defense against the charge of hiring an unauthorized employee. This means that you can legally work for someone if you can convince them to hire you; if they do so without checking their defense will instead be that you were not unauthorized. In practice that will be difficult to do except in informal situations, of course.